# LINQ Query different collections with the same logic

Tags: c#, .net, linq, collections

This problem has been puzzling me for a while now, let me break it down a bit.

I need to query two different collections with the same logic of `Where`, `Select` statements and things, and I don't know this logic in advance. Say I have two collections:

```
var arrayOne = {"Germane", "Henry", "Charissa", "Evan", "Zorita"};
var arrayTwo = {"Athena", "Darryl", "Zelenia", "Honorato", "Macon"};
```

And some filtering logic:

```
var result = arrayOne.Where(x => x.Length > 3).Select(x => x.Length);
```

How do I copy this logic to the second array without copying the code itself? There's a way to do this via delegates (which is my current one)

```
Func<IEnumerable<string>, IEnumerable<int>> query = x => x.Where(x => x.Length > 3).Select(x => x.Length);
var result1 = query(arrayOne);
var result2 = query(arrayTwo );
```

But I need to build queries progressively, not inline, like

```
var query = SomeQueryGenerator.CreateQuery();
query.Where(x => x.Length > 3)
if(someCondition)
{
    // Totally random query
    query.Where(x => x.Length % 2 == 0);
} 
var result = query(arrayOne);
```

---

This was the question. Now let me show what I have done so far (and break my case down even more)

The problem arose when we tried to import of loads of data into our DB. This data has about 20k rows and it can contain some duplicates (which we don't want to store), so it's very important to check if we already have specific rows (it checks by some legal IDs). We use NHibernate as ORM and by default it flushes `INSERT`s and `UPDATE`s quite often, before every `SELECT` statement or at any other time.

The problem is that these flushes take very long, so long that it takes up to 10 hours to load all 20k rows into DB. The most obvious way is to set our current `Session.FlushMode` to `FlushMode.Never` and flush it at the end of the import. This way 20k rows import for about 10 minutes. But the problem is that this way when we query, we don't see our duplicates as they are not in the DB yet, and our queries like `.Where(x => x.LegalId == someId)` don't find anything even when there **is** actually a saved row. I decided to utilize our `Session` 1st level cache for this task, as all of our saved entites are first written in it's cache and then to DB when the `Flush` occurs (it may be not actually written to DB until our `transaction.Commit`, but it will properly find these entites with a query).
I've set up a helper class that can query both cache and original DB and it properly finds entites in cache that are not yet in DB (inline delegate example above)

But I need to be able to query things progressively, and I'm totally lost now.
We can't just get an `Expression` from one `IQueryable` and paste it to another. We can't create some dummy `IQueryable` or `IEnumerable` object and pass it around, throwing `.Where` or `.Select` because we will be tied up to a particular source, and we can't swap the sources either (at least I have not found a way to do it).

I need some new thoughts on this question, thanks in advance.

-- UPDATE on data duplications

We can't preprocess our data, let me explain why.

Let's say we have buildings in our files. Some buildinds can belong to an organization. If we encounter a building with a specified organization, we need to create it and store in DB. This way we have not only buildings (which themselves are not duplicated), but their organizations too. It's totally possible that several buildings will have same organizations, but we don't need to create these organizations more than one time. Of course we can first parse this file, fetch all organizations, import them first and then import constructions only, but this is too complicated, and, as I've stated in a comment, the problem is more generic one, it's outside of the scope of this import logic

Comment: I can't help but ask, can't you preprocess the data first (deduplicate it) and then just bulk-insert in one go?

Comment: Is it just the 'where' clause that needs to be built dynamically?

Comment: @PatrykĆwiek It's more complicated than that, there are some things that don't let us just delete duplicate data because it's not just "duplicate rows". I will add an example, please take a look when it's ready.
Overall, it's a more generic problem. I'm pretty satisfied with my current solution, but our teamlead wants me to take this query logic outside of data importing and make it project-wise.

@codemonkey No, we need to support all the queries including `Projecting`, `Filtering`, and `Element` methods

Comment: @KumoKairo In the example you give, if `someCondition` is true then the result switches from being a sequence of strings to a sequence of integers. Is that intentional or do you always have a fixed result type after constructing the query?

Comment: @MatthewStrawbridge
Good question. I've made a mistake in this "out of the head" example. No, these conditional queries with type substitution won't happen. Let me edit my question, and thanks for asking. Something that can happen - we can create a different `query` variable with a different return type, but surely, we won't be able to access it outside of the `if` construction if we don't want to clutter our code with different `null` initialized variables

Answer (score 0):

Still not very sure on what you're trying to do exactely, but i guess this can help you in the right direction:

```
    var arrayOne = new []{"Germane", "Henry", "Charissa", "Evan", "Zorita"};
    var arrayTwo = new []{"Athena", "Darryl", "Zelenia", "Honorato", "Macon"};

    //var result1 = arrayOne.Where(x => x.Length > 3).Select(x => x.Length);

    bool condition1 = true;
    bool condition2 = false;
    bool condition3 = true;

    var fnc = (Func<IEnumerable, IEnumerable>)(source =>
    {
        var qry = source;
        if (condition1)
        {
            qry = qry.Cast<string>().Where(x => x.Length > 3);
        }

        if (condition2)
        {
            qry = qry.Cast<int>().Where(x => x < 10);
        }

        if (condition3)
        {
            return qry.Cast<string>().Select(x => x.Length);
        }

        return qry;
    });

    var result_v2_1 = fnc(arrayOne);
    var result_v2_2 = fnc(arrayTwo);
```

Mind that setting consition1 and condition2 to true, will result in errors.  Also mind that condition2 combined with an input of String[] will also result in an error.

Comment: Thanks for your time and the answer, but it's not what I need, because it's hardcoded a to particular order and contents of the query, but as I specified in the question, I don't know this logic in advance.

Comment: @KumoKairo : Changed it to two Enumerables, should be 'open' enough to do anything with it.

Comment: The point is - it has `.Where` and other queries inside, along with the `if` conditions. What I mean by *'I don't know query logic in advance'* is that I should be able to just query my collections without specifying any branching logic **inside** the delegate. It has noting to do with the `IEnumerable` stuff. And you are casting your `IEnumerable` to specific types, it's no difference frow your original answer.

Answer (score 0):

## Option 1: Changing the source

Although LINQ queries are bound to a sequence, that sequence can be changed and the query re-evaluated. So you can do this kind of thing:

```
var arrayOne = new[] {"Germane", "Henry", "Charissa", "Evan", "Zorita"};
var arrayTwo = new[] {"Athena", "Darryl", "Zelenia", "Honorato", "Macon"};

// bind to an empty sequence to start with
var source = new List<string>();

var query = source.Where (x => x.Length > 3);
if (true)
{
    query = query.Where (x => x.Length % 2 == 0);
}

// change the sequence once
source.AddRange(arrayOne);
var resultOne = query.ToArray();    
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", resultOne));

// change the sequence again
source.Clear();
source.AddRange(arrayTwo);
var resultTwo = query.ToList();
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", resultTwo));
```

The first `Console.WriteLine` outputs this:

> Charissa, Evan, Zorita

And the second one outputs this:

> Athena, Darryl, Honorato

## Option 2: Using a method

A simpler solution would be to create methods for any of these sequence manipulations instead of trying to do it all inline:

```
private static IEnumerable<string> Filter(IEnumerable<string> sequence)
{
    var bigOnes = sequence.Where (s => s.Length > 3);
    if (true)
    {
        bigOnes = bigOnes.Where (s =>  s.Length % 2 == 0);
    }
    return bigOnes;
}
```

...

```
var resultThree = Filter(arrayOne);  
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", resultThree));

var resultFour = Filter(arrayTwo);
Console.WriteLine (string.Join(", ", resultFour));
```

Comment: Actually, I thought of `Concat`ing the sequences first, it's even more simple than your example, but it won't work for my case of `IQueryable + IEnumerable` targets because the `IQueryable` part of it won't find it's way to SQL statement, it will just fetch *all* the data from the DB and then filter it locally. Thanks anyways